# Error on : Because every version of integration_test from sdk depends on vm_service 6.0.1-nullsafety.1 and dwds ^7.1.0 depends on vm_service 5.5.0,

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I'm new to flutter and I've been having dependency issues on flutter Keep having this same error

````
Because every version of integration_test from sdk depends on vm_service 6.0.1-nullsafety.1 and dwds ^7.1.0 depends on vm_service 5.5.0, integration_test from sdk is incompatible with dwds ^7.1.0.
So, because brandapp depends on both dwds ^7.1.0 and integration_test any from sdk, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because brandapp depends on both dwds ^7.1.0 and integration_test any from sdk, version solving failed.)```
````

Comment: Have you checked [this article](https://pratikbutani.medium.com/flutter-2-upgrade-flutter-version-solving-failed-error-33ac1087cb6b)